# Regular expression for csv with commas and no quotes

Tags: regex, csv, quote

I'm trying to parse really complicated csv, which is generated wittout any quotes for columns with commas.
 The only tip I get, that commas with whitespace before or after are included in field.

```
Jake,HomePC,Microsoft VS2010, Microsoft Office 2010
```

Should be parsed to

```
Jake
HomePC
Microsoft VS2010, Microsoft Office 2010
```

Can anybody advice please on how to include "\s," and ,"\s" to column body.

Comment: Split on `,(?!\s)(?<!\s)` perhaps?

Comment: @Wrikken, not so good at regex, can you please whow usage sample. Thanks.

Comment: This clearly isn't a CSV file if it's not escaping the data correctly. If at all possible I would get the soure of the data to create a [properly formatted CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)

Comment: @Brad, I have no opportunity to change, have to work with what I get

Comment: @Wrikken, seems your advice helped, can you write it as an aswer so I can mark it.

Comment: @Wrikken you need to check for spaces before the "," too

Comment: @Brad - well... the file contains values, and, formatted correctly or in a parseable manner or not, those values are separated by commas - right? wouldn't that make it a comma-separated-value file (or CSV file)? perhaps there is an ISO standard somewhere the defines CSV of which I am not aware?

Comment: @CodeJockey see the link to wikipedia in my comment and specifically the section titled "Basic rules and examples" where it mentions "Fields with embedded commas must be quoted". Anyone who has had to deal with a poorly thoughtout, home-grown file format like poor Johnny_D here, knows the pain

Comment: @Brad - My point is outlined in the ["Lack of a standard" section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Lack_of_a_standard) of that self-same article - though there is an RFC (and several other recommendations), there is no standard - I'm not saying he is not in a bad situation, or that he would not be wise to push for "properly" formatted source data -- because it would be silly to rely on ignoring commas followed by spaces to separate the data. It's just that he is, in fact, dealing with values separated by commas, stored in a file -- thus, "CSV" is not inaccurate.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh: Ah, I misplaced the `(?<!\s)` I see, was running out of the door to work when I posted that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your language supports lookbehind assertions, split on

```
(?<!\s),(?!\s)
```

In C#:

```
string[] splitArray = Regex.Split(subjectString, 
    @"(?<!\s) # Assert that the previous character isn't whitespace
    ,         # Match a comma
    (?!\s)    # Assert that the following character isn't whitespace", 
    RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: Yes, just remember to put the regex in a verbatim string (`@"..."`).

Answer (score 0):

split by r"(?!\s+),(?!\s+)"

in python you can do this like

```
import re
re.split(r"(?!\s+),(?!\s+)", s) # s is your string
```

Comment: This is incorrect and inelegant. You need a lookbehind assertion, and you don't need quantifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It gave me the desired result which you have mentioned.

```
StringBuilder testt = new StringBuilder("Jake,HomePC,Microsoft VS2010, Microsoft Office 2010,Microsoft VS2010, Microsoft Office 2010");
Pattern varPattern = Pattern.compile("[a-z0-9],[a-z0-9]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher varMatcher = varPattern.matcher(testt);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
int startIndex = 0, endIndex = 0;
boolean found = false;
while (varMatcher.find()) {
endIndex = varMatcher.start()+1;
if (startIndex == 0) {
list.add(testt.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
} else {
startIndex++;
list.add(testt.substring(startIndex, endIndex));
}
startIndex = endIndex;
found = true;
}
if (found) {
if (startIndex == 0) {
list.add(testt.substring(startIndex));
} else {
list.add(testt.substring(startIndex + 1));
}
}
for (String s : list) {
System.out.println(s);
}
```

Please note that the code is in Java.