# Advice on Regex expression for a csv when quotes don't block out messages

Tags: regex, csv

I have a CSV that is created and doesn't quote out text comments from a column and includes new lines.

[Regular expression for csv with commas and no quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469655/regular-expression-for-csv-with-commas-and-no-quotes) is a similiar question but he doesn't have another line or additional columns to parse through.

A line of text in the csv can look like this:

```
    1, 15231, 123123, 1231, word word word, YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sss, 13453, **This would be the section with any character for users to communicate and the db stores and 
new lines to record communication**, YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sss, User name, 12412413, 01231231, 123,12,,*ASTERIX USED*, YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss.sss
```

Then another new line and something like about would parse through,

So far I've tried this

```
/(\d+?),(\d+?),(\d+?),(\d+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+(?=,\d{4})),
```

But I can't seem to get past the instances if there are date references in the comments section of the csv.

Farely new to regex and the (?=) is new to me as I had to go beyond simple regex patterns.

Comment: This is a solved problem.  Rather than writing your own CSV parser from scratch, use a proper CSV parser for the language that you're using.  What are you writing in?  Perl?  If so, use Text::CSV or Text::CSV_XS.

Comment: @AndyLester The problem is that the OP's data is not well-formed CSV, so a CSV parser may incorrectly interpret the user-entered field as multiple fields.

Comment: @F.J is correct - The CSV is not well-formed and I'm trying to work around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the exact number of fields that there should be, then you can use the following method:

- For each "normal" field that will not contain commas, use `[^,]*`
- For the user entered field which may contain commas, use `.*`
- Separate each field with a comma

For example if you have five total fields and the third is entered by the user, you would use the following regex:

```
([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*),([^,]*),([^,]*)
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/E6785bWW0R

If the user entered field may contain line breaks, make sure you enable the option so that `.` matches line break characters (often `s`, or a constant like `DOTALL`, in some languages you can prefix your regex with `(?s)`).  Alternatively, just replace `.*` with `[\s\S]*`, which will match anything regardless of options used.

Comment: I tried it but here is the best I can do with a new line creating a new match.... [here it is in rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/GiFJOGvbC7) Any advice on this?

Comment: How many total fields do you expect for the data on the rubular?  Here is one potential way to modify it: http://www.rubular.com/r/oir2sB2wxW